# Как правильно употреблять предлоги «С» и «ОТ»

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, предлоги, числительные, выбор-варианта

Возник вопрос. Как верно: «Идет набор детей «с» или «от» 4 до 14 лет»?

Comment: Либо вот такой вариант: «Набор детей «от» или «с» 4 до 14 лет»

Answer (score 1):

Варианты **синонимичные**, но различаются **оттенками** значений и по **стилю**.

(1) *Идет набор детей **от 4 до 14 лет**.*  Указан возрастной интервал и дополнительно — начальный возраст. Стиль скорее нейтральный;  вариант более предпочтительный.

(2) *Идет набор детей **с 4 до 14 лет**.* Указан возрастной интервал; стиль разговорный.

При выборе использован материал: [Управление в русском языке](https://gufo.me/dict/rection_rosenthal)

**ОТ — С**

3. (при указании длительности или **протяженности** чего-л.) Предлоги **синонимичны**, различаются оттенками значения. Перерыв на обед с двенадцати до часу (**временной отрезок**) — ...от двенадцати до часу (**добавочное значение исходного момента**). Одет во все новое с головы до пят (пространственный отрезок). — Окинул взором от головы до пят (добавочное указание исходной точки).

Comment: Огромное спасибо за подробный ответ.